# Proper share type for st_twitter_hcount and st_fblike_hcount (Dynamic specification through JS)

Tags: javascript, social-media, sharethis

Here is my test page: http://ignitepixels.com/test/shareThisTest.html

I am having an issue with dynamically generating ShareThis buttons with Javascript. For most of my buttons I want to use the "chicklet" type. But I also want to include the twitter share hcount and facebook like hcount buttons.

Normally (without javascript) you would use something like:

```
<span class='st_twitter'></span>
<span class='st_facebook'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin'></span>
<span class='st_googleplus'></span>
<span class='st_email'></span>
<span class='st_reddit'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount'></span>
<span class='st_fblike_hcount'></span>
```

But I am trying to dynamically generate these buttons using:

```
stWidget.addEntry({
"service" : shareService,
"element" : document.getElementById(shareElemendID),
"url" : shareURL,
"title" : shareTitle,
"type" : shareType,
"onhover" : false
});
```

(Note: my shareType var is dynamically generated with javascript. You can see the javascript by viewing the test page's source.)

I can use `"chicklet"` as the hard value for `"type"` but this does not render the hcount buttons correctly. So I have a bit of js that determines whether to use "chicklet" or "hcount", but even hcount has funny results. (See http://ignitepixels.com/test/shareThisTest.html under header "Dynamic ShareThis Buttons").

Anyone have any clue what type should I be using for the hcount buttons I am using in my javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future users, here's the answer I received from a ShareThis Support Agent (http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/questions/862200-proper-share-type-for-st-twitter-hcount-and-st-fblike-hcount-dynamic-specification-through-js-#sthash.F82qZiuZ.dpbs):

You are getting malformed buttons because you are using an incorrect "service" name. You cannot use service names like these - "st_twitter_hcount"

Please use service names as - "twitter","facebook" and then you can specify the button type in "type" as "hcount" or "vcount".

Below is an example on how to achieve this using the code that you have implemented.

```
shareServices : ['twitter', 'facebook', 'linkedin', 'googleplus', 'email', 'reddit', 'st_twitter', 'st_fblike','st_wordpress','st_linkedin']

shareType = ( shareService.match(/^st_/) ) ? 'hcount' : 'chicklet' ;
if( shareService.match(/^st_/) )
{
    shareService=shareService.substring(3);
};
```